# Get only face of tagged friend in a group photo in facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-php-sdk

I have obtained images in which my friend has been tagged.

```
select link from photo where object_id in 
    (select object_id from photo_tag where subject=frindID
```

I have an image in which the my friend is tagged. The image is a group photo. I need to take only the face of my friend? how to do it using facebook api?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously you cannot do that with Graph API.!!

But you can have the position of their tags: `xcoord,ycoord` in the pic.- if you can manipulate the actual photo with these.

Reference- [Photo Tag](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/photo_tag/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can I use any FQL query or any other options to do this?

Comment: You need the face from a photo, so you should apply some image processing at your end, how could facebook provide this?

Comment: Does the xcoord and ycoord return the co-ordinates of the particular face in a group photo?

Comment: Can;t say face, but the tag position (mostly it would be face)

Comment: Can I get a query on how to get the x and y co-ordinates?

Comment: `select xcoord,ycoord, object_id from photo_tag where subject={uid}`

Comment: I have used the above command and  got the xco-ordinate and yco-ordinates. But I am getting links for different size of images like ( 640 * 480, 970*600 etc., ). For which size this x and y co-ordinate is the returning?

Comment: You can reasearch on that, I'm not sure of that